# Java Regex: check is a string has specific structure: *test_text*

Tags: java, regex

How would I do that? I want a string like this

```
*test_text*
```

to be recognized as the patterned string, but a string like this:

```
*test____text*
```

or

```
*test_*[text*
```

or
`*test_again_text*`
not to be recognized

Comment: You can try this [`^\*[a-z]+_[a-z]+\*$`](https://regex101.com/r/btwE7c/2/), if you want to allow anything else than alphabet in text you can add up in character class, i.e `[a-z\d]` to allow digits as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression might be desired here:

```
(?i)^\*[a-z0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+\*$
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?i)^\\*[a-z0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+\\*$";
        final String string = "*test_text*\n"
             + "*test____text*\n"
             + "*test_*[text*\n"
             + "*test_again_tex";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: *test_text*
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ombIEH/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ombIEH/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/m1rCcV/1/)

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! I was wondering, though, is there a way to make it work with this string: `*cat_dog* fdfd`? If I replace the space with newline: `*cat_dog*\nfdfd` it works, however with space it doesn't. I tried changing `Pattern.MULTILINE` to some other one, but none of the patterns I tried worked.